# Parsing _embedded items from JSON HAL response

Tags: java, json, jackson, spring-hateoas

We are trying to parse the below JSON to get a list of people.

JSON Response:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "people": [
      {
        "id": 35356,
        "name": "Jon",
        "description": "Test",
        "type": "person",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/api/v1/50452/people/35356"
          },
          "items": {
            "href": "http://localhost/api/v1/50452/items?person_id=35356"
          },
          "enabled_services": [
            {
              "title": "Water Company",
              "href": "http://localhost/api/v1/50452/services/103890"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 46363,
        "name": "Kevin",
        "description": "",
        "type": "person",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/api/v1/50452/people/46363"
          },
          "items": {
            "href": "http://localhost/api/v1/50452/items?person_id=46363"
          },
          "enabled_services": [
            {
              "title": "Water Company",
              "href": "http://localhost/api/v1/50452/services/103890"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost/api/v1/50452/people"
    }
  }
}
```

Our code:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Person>> resource = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Person>>() {};

Traverson traverson = new Traverson(new URI("http://localhost/api/v1/people"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

// Create our own LinkDiscoverer as our service returns application/json instead of application/json+hal
List<LinkDiscoverer> linkDiscoverers = new ArrayList<>();
linkDiscoverers.add(new JsonPathLinkDiscoverer("$._links..['%s']..href", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
traverson.setLinkDiscoverers(linkDiscoverers);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("App-Key", Globals.Appkey);
headers.add("App-Id", Globals.AppId);

Resources<Person> personResources = traverson.follow("people").withHeaders(headers).toObject(resource);
```

However we are getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to find link with rel 'people' in response {"_embedded":{"people":[{"id":31350,"name":"Jon Blue","description":"Developer","type":"person","deleted":false,"disabled":false,"company_id":50452,"order":31350,"phone_prefix":"44","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost/api/v1/50452/people/31350"},"items":{"href":"http://localhost/api/v1/50452/items?person_id=31350"},"enabled_services":[{"title":"Water ...
```

Based on the (very limited) client docs this seems to be the correct way to do things. Does anyone know what we might be missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Traverson` is meant to be used to follow links:

> Component to ease traversing hypermedia APIs by following links with
>   relation types. Highly inspired by the equally named JavaScript
>   library.

There is no link with rel `people` in your response, so it cannot be followed.

I could imagine you wanted to call the top-level resource that has a link to `people`:

```
Traverson traverson = new Traverson(new URI("http://localhost/api/v1/"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
```

Otherwise I would suggest to use a `RestTemplate` to get the Resource:

```
restTemplate.exchange(
                URI.create("http://localhost/api/v1/people"),
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new HttpEntity<Void>(headers),
                resource).getBody();
```